# pyautogui changing MINIMUM_SLEEP makes moveTo function not use duration input

Tags: python, pyautogui

So, this piece of code:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.PAUSE = 0
pyautogui.MINIMUM_SLEEP = 0
pyautogui.MINIMUM_DURATION = 0
pyautogui.moveTo(100,100,duration=1)
```

Makes the mouse takes 20+ second to reach its destination. The cause is the MINIMUM_SLEEP value, no matter the duration added it will take the same time (ages). Is there a way around this? - Is there any way to make the mouse movement smooth and still set the duration?

I am very surprised I haven't seen any comments on this. Thanks.